# Increase buffer size in the new Windows Terminal

Tags: windows-terminal

The default buffer size in the new Windows terminal (https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) is too small and quickly gets full when reading a large file. I could not find a way to increase it.

In the old Windows terminal, one could change the buffer size using the method described in this answer:
[Windows Command Prompt: How do I increase my buffer?](https://superuser.com/questions/378313/windows-command-prompt-how-do-i-increase-my-buffer/378321)

Comment: [Feature Request: configurable screen buffer size · Issue #3612 · microsoft/terminal · GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/3612) has a workaround

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is controlled by the [`historySize`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/profile-advanced#history-size) profile setting.  The default value of 9001 can be changed via several different methods:

- To change it for a single profile:

  1. From the Windows Terminal drop-down menu, select "Settings"
  2. Select the profile you want to change
  3. Chose the "Advanced" tab
  4. Increase the "History Size" to your desired setting
  5. Save
- To change it for all profiles (available in the latest Windows Terminal release from a few days ago):

  1. From the Windows Terminal drop-down menu, select "Settings"
  2. Select "Defaults" under the Profiles section
  3. Chose the "Advanced" tab
  4. Increase the "History Size" to your desired setting
  5. Save

It is also possible, of course, to modify the `settings.json` file directly.

Depending on your shell, you may also want to consider using something like `tmux`, which has a built in buffer with more features than those typically available in terminal applications.  It's entirely possible, using WSL and a bit of [configuration](https://superuser.com/a/1643117/1210833), to even set this up for PowerShell or CMD.